# Groovy render as JSON java.sql.timestamp in In JavaScript milliseconds not displayed

Tags: javascript, json, grails, timestamp

I have a `java.util.ArrayList` which contains the red marked value:[image]

if I render it with `render relations as JSON` then in JavaScript the value is the following:
[image]

The milliseconds are gone, if I understand it right the value of `receiveDate` is a string so there is no way to parse it to another format.

Is there a way to render the value that the milliseconds are not gone ?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1

```
import grails.converters.JSON

def r = [now: new Date(), name: 'Roong']
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {o -> o.getTime()}
println(r as JSON)
```

Result 1

```
{
  "now": 1356595418027,
  "name": "Roong"
}
```

or you can set in Config.groovy
Method 2

```
grails.converters.json.date = "javascript"
```

Result 2

```
{
  "now": new Date(1356595418027),
  "name": "Roong"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the missing part to another key-value pair, using method

```
java.sql.Timestamp.getNanos()
```

and restore the complete value in javascript by consolidating the two parts. For example:

```
String receiveDate = grails.converters.JSON.parse(jsonData).data[0].receiveDate
def formatDate = receiveDate.replace('Z','.'+ dt.getNanos().toString()).replace('T', ' ')
def tsDate = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(formatDate)
println 'The timestamp is : ' +  tsDate
```